# How do I convert strings to access multidimension dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dictionary

```
mydict = { 'name': "Hello",
           'address': { 'place': 'India',
                        'street': {
                                   'One': 'Street one', 'Two': 'Street Two' }
                       },
            'Job': 'Sleep' }
```

So I can access the value of Street one like mydict['address']['street']['One']

Now I am thinking of simplifying this like this

I have another dictionary like below

```
dict_map = {'Name': ['name'],
            'AddressOne': ['address','street','One'] }
```

Is there any way I can directly access the element 'One' using  dict_map['AddressOne']

Thanks
~S

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. What are you trying?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev - I'm also waiting for code from last 24 mins

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Some how in my search , this thread didn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

There are really many ways to do this. For example:

```
class DictMapper(object):

    def __init__(self, d, d_map):
        self.d = d
        self.dict_map = d_map

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return reduce(lambda res, path: res[path], self.dict_map[item], self.d)
```

Usage:

```
dm = DictMapper(mydict, dict_map)
print dm["AddressOne"]
```